# How to Type Hint a variable that must be an instance of a class or of its subclasses in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

Let's say that I have a class `Animal` and some subclasses of Animal like `Dog` and `Cat`.
I want to **type hint** a variable named `a` in order to declare that it can be **both** an Animal's instance or one of the subclass of Animal instance.

- Example of me trying to type hint :

```
class Animal :
   pass

class Dog(Animal) :
   pass

class Cat(Animal) :
   pass

a : type[Animal] = Dog() #But could have been Animal() or Cat()
```

As you can see I have been using this syntax : **type[ParentClassName]** .
However, as I have read on the typing documentation, **type[ParentClassName]** is for a class and not instances of a class (see : [https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type](https://stackoverflow.com)).

*(Note that `type[ClassName]` is the same as `typing.Type[ClassName]` since Python 3.9)*

The main focus of the type hint I'm searching for is the fact that it can be **both** an Animal's instance or a Dog/Cat's instance **while being mypy friendly**.

- *So is there a way to do this by type hinting ?*

Sorry for any mistakes, english isn't my first language.
And thanks to anyone who will try to answer my question.

Comment: It's sounds like you're just looking for `a: Animal`. Does that not suite your needs?

Comment: Note that `a: type[Animal] = Dog()` is a type error. Either `a: Animal = Dog()` or `a: type[Animal] = Dog` would be correct.

Comment: Does it work on mypy even if a is a Dog() ?

Comment: Yes, subclasses are compatible with their parent classes as a basic tenet of OOP.

Comment: using `type` here is completely wrong

Comment: @JSaur yes, it will definitely work , `a: Animal = Dog()`. However, `a` will only be able to access the `Animal` interface then in a type-safe manner (at runtime, Python isn't statically typed, of course)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Brian61354270.
I will edit my post so that people having the same questions as me will get their answer more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly my goal was to have a way to declare that my variable `a` is an `Animal`.
However my concern was that if `a` become an instance of `Dog` , even if `Dog` inherit from `Animal`, would `a` still be considered an `Animal`.

The answer is yes and so the way to declare it with type hint is :

```
class Animal :
    pass

class Dog(Animal) :
    pass

a: Animal = Dog()
```

In fact the reason why it's correct come from the **Subtype relationship**s notion described in PEP 483 (see : https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#subtype-relationships).

Thanks to **Brian61354270** and **juanpa.arrivillaga** for their answers.